# User not authenticated on change password in AWS user pool

Tags: ionic3

[image]
[image]

When I try to call change password API at that time I got User not authenticated error in cognito user pool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I have struggled with this as well and finally got this solution.

You should get the Authenticated User

```
export const GetAuthenticatedUser = () => {
    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
        UserPoolId: process.env.OGNITO_POOL_ID,
        ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
    });
    return userPool.getCurrentUser();
};
```

Then you should call the getSesion() method and try to change the password within its callback, otherwise it doesn't work.

```
 export const ChangePassword = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const currentUser = GetAuthenticatedUser();
        if (currentUser) {
            currentUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    currentUser.changePassword(data.old_password, data.password, function (
                        err,
                        res
                    ) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(GetCognitoError(err.code + '_ChangePassword'));
                        } else {
                            resolve(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            reject('User is not authenticated')
        }
    });
};
```