# User not authenticated error while using change password in AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement change password using AWS SDK but I keep getting the User not authorized error on calling the change password method. I have tried fixes like initiating signup and using the auth token generated to call change password, and also getting user details before calling change password (which seemed to work for a few similar issues). Would like to know if there is something I am missing or something I should be doing different.

I want to get a fix for the AWS SDK, though I have seen it working on AWS Amplify.

Few fixes I have tried implementing

[User not authenticated on change password in AWS user pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990599/user-not-authenticated-on-change-password-in-aws-user-pool)

https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/71

Really appreciate any help I could get on this.